# How to continue \startParagraphNumbers in ConteXt

Tags: numbering, context, paragraphs, legal-style

I just started using ConteXt to typeset some legal documents. The paragraphs in these docs need to be numbered sequentially. And though I did find a code for this in here [ConteXt Ref \startParagraphNumbers](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Paragraph_Enumeration), the problem is that the numbering resets everytime it's interrupted (see below)

[image]

I have no luck in finding a solution (short of manually entering the numbers or learning lua? which is way beyond me). I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks.

(PS. I have used parano.sty/LateX but switched to ConteXt recently since it seems tidier)

Min-Sample.

```
\definepapersize[pb][width=8.5in,height=13in]
\setuppapersize[pb]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=singesided,location={footer,right}]

\newcounter\Paracount
\setcounter\Paracount
\def\Paragraphnumber%
   {\increment\Paracount
    \Paracount.~ }
\def\startParagraphNumbers%
   {\par \begingroup \appendtoks \Paragraphnumber \to \everypar}
\def\stopParagraphNumbers%
   {\par \endgroup}



\definefontfamily [myfamily][rm][XCharter][features={default,quality}]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [ss][Calibre][features={default,quality}]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [mm][pagella][features={default,quality}]
\setupbodyfont [myfamily,10pt]

\setupalign[hz,hanging]
\setupindenting[yes,medium,first]
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\starttext

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc feugiat in sapien nec efficitur. 

\startParagraphNumbers
Donec at mauris ut orci consequat vulputate. Proin vestibulum magna commodo, tincidunt nulla non, fermentum risus. 

Nulla vitae ornare tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sit amet feugiat orci, quis elementum orci.  
\stopParagraphNumbers

\startitemize[2,packed]
\item Nam ut ligula justo.
\item Integer a lacus fermentum, tincidunt libero id,
\item blandit sem. Sed gravida mauris ac sem finibus, 
\stopitemize

\startParagraphNumbers
ac suscipit diam dignissim. Vivamus tristique tempor nisi, eget vehicula velit maximus eu. 

Phasellus vel ornare est, sit amet volutpat nunc. Donec est nulla, porttitor a convallis vitae, pulvinar ut ligula. 
\stopParagraphNumbers

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably shouldn't answer this since I never use ConTeXt, but what about:

```
\def\pauseParagraphNumbers{\xdef\savedParacount{\Paracount} \par\endgroup}
\def\resumeParagraphNumbers{\par \begingroup \let\Paracount=\savedParacount \appendtoks \Paragraphnumber \to \everypar}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
\definepapersize[pb][width=8.5in,height=13in]
\setuppapersize[pb]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=singesided,location={footer,right}]

\newcounter\Paracount
\setcounter\Paracount
\def\Paragraphnumber%
   {\increment\Paracount
    \Paracount.~ }
\def\startParagraphNumbers%
   {\par \begingroup \appendtoks \Paragraphnumber \to \everypar}
\def\stopParagraphNumbers%
   {\par \endgroup}    

\def\pauseParagraphNumbers{\xdef\savedParacount{\Paracount} \par\endgroup}
\def\resumeParagraphNumbers{\par \begingroup \let\Paracount=\savedParacount  \appendtoks  \Paragraphnumber \to \everypar}


\definefontfamily [myfamily][rm][XCharter][features={default,quality}]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [ss][Calibre][features={default,quality}]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [mm][pagella][features={default,quality}]
\setupbodyfont [myfamily,10pt]

\setupalign[hz,hanging]
\setupindenting[yes,medium,first]
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\starttext

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc feugiat in sapien nec efficitur.

\startParagraphNumbers
Donec at mauris ut orci consequat vulputate. Proin vestibulum magna commodo, tincidunt nulla non, fermentum risus.

Nulla vitae ornare tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sit amet feugiat orci, quis elementum orci.
\pauseParagraphNumbers

Just to see:
\savedParacount

\startitemize[2,packed]
\item Nam ut ligula justo.
\item Integer a lacus fermentum, tincidunt libero id,
\item blandit sem. Sed gravida mauris ac sem finibus,
\stopitemize

\resumeParagraphNumbers
ac suscipit diam dignissim. Vivamus tristique tempor nisi, eget vehicula velit maximus eu.

Phasellus vel ornare est, sit amet volutpat nunc. Donec est nulla, porttitor a convallis vitae, pulvinar ut ligula.    
\pauseParagraphNumbers

\startitemize[2,packed]
\item Nam ut ligula justo.
\item Integer a lacus fermentum, tincidunt libero id,
\item blandit sem. Sed gravida mauris ac sem finibus,
\stopitemize

\resumeParagraphNumbers
ac suscipit diam dignissim. Vivamus tristique tempor nisi, eget vehicula velit maximus eu.

Phasellus vel ornare est, sit amet volutpat nunc. Donec est nulla, porttitor a convallis vitae, pulvinar ut ligula.    
\stopParagraphNumbers

\stoptext
```

Comment: Hey THANKS! I just tried it and IT WORKS! thank you.

Comment: @timcabs -- Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `\setupparagraphintro` to insert a number at the begin of each paragraph. With the `reset` keyword you can disable the insertion of the number.

```
\definelabel[parnumber][text=,headstyle=]

\definestartstop
  [ParagraphNumbers]
  [before={\setupparagraphintro[each][\parnumber~]},
   after={\setupparagraphintro[reset]}]

\setupindenting[yes,medium,first]
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\starttext

\noindentation
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc feugiat in sapien nec efficitur. 

\startParagraphNumbers
Donec at mauris ut orci consequat vulputate. Proin vestibulum magna commodo, tincidunt nulla non, fermentum risus. 

Nulla vitae ornare tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sit amet feugiat orci, quis elementum orci.  
\stopParagraphNumbers

\startitemize[2,packed]
\item Nam ut ligula justo.
\item Integer a lacus fermentum, tincidunt libero id,
\item blandit sem. Sed gravida mauris ac sem finibus, 
\stopitemize

\startParagraphNumbers
ac suscipit diam dignissim. Vivamus tristique tempor nisi, eget vehicula velit maximus eu. 

Phasellus vel ornare est, sit amet volutpat nunc. Donec est nulla, porttitor a convallis vitae, pulvinar ut ligula. 
\stopParagraphNumbers

\stoptext
```

Comment: Hi that also worked. Thanks. I had to change this `\definelabel[parnumber][text=,headstyle=,after=. ,]` to add period and space after number.